# How can you call a non static class from a fragment or how can you call a non static function in a static class

Tags: android, android-listview

I had to move the adapter class for **listview** to the main activity so that I could access the **viewpager** and find it through **view**

But when I began to call this class from a fragment to me began to give an error:

> error: an enclosing instance that contains MainActivity.Adapter is required

Because the class is not static

Here's the question, is There any way to work around the error or replace the findViewById () method?

**Adapter**

```
   public static class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<HelpAdapter> objects;
    String url ;
    private SharedPreferences settings;

    Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<HelpAdapter> products) {

        ctx = context;
        objects = products;

        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    // кол-во элементов
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    // элемент по позиции
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    // id по позиции
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // пункт списка
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // используем созданные, но не используемые view
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }
        settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences("Settings", ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                final TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView1_2);
                AlertDialog.Builder deleted = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                deleted.setMessage("Удалить урок?").setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        ViewPager viewPager2;
                        MainActivity.PagerAdapter pagerAdapter1;
                        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.rager);
                        url = settings.getString("Day","Monday.txt");
                        StringBuffer stringBuffer1 = new StringBuffer();
                        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

                        try {
                            FileInputStream read = ctx.openFileInput(url);
                            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(read);
                            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                            String temp_read, temp;

                            while ((temp_read = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                                temp = stringBuffer1.append(temp_read).toString();
                                stringBuffer1.setLength(0);


                                if  (!temp.equals(textView.getText()))
                                    stringBuffer.append(temp_read).append("\n");
                            }

                            bufferedReader.close();
                            reader.close();
                            read.close();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                        try {
                            FileOutputStream write = ctx.openFileOutput(url,ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            write.write(stringBuffer.toString().getBytes());
                            write.close();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        switch (url) {
                            case "Wednesday.txt" :
                                classWednesday classWednesday = new classWednesday();
                                classWednesday.Start();
                                pagerAdapter1 = new MainActivity.PagerAdapter(new FragmentActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
                                viewPager2.setAdapter(pagerAdapter1);
                                pagerAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                break;


                        }

                    }
                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = deleted.create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Удаление урока");
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });



        HelpAdapter p = getProduct(position);


        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(p.pozic);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1_2)).setText(p.name);

        return view;
    }



    HelpAdapter getProduct(int position) {
        return ((HelpAdapter) getItem(position));
    }


}
```

**Fragment**

```
import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


public class classWednesday extends Fragment {
    private ListView lvMain;
    private List<Fragment> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<HelpAdapter> products = new ArrayList<>();
    Integer num = 0;
    private SharedPreferences settings;
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser && (getActivity()!=null)) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("Day","Wednesday.txt" );
            editor.apply();

        }




    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.wednesday, container,false);
        Start();
        lvMain = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.lvWednesday);
        MainActivity.Adapter adapter = new MainActivity.Adapter(getActivity(),products);
        lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
        settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (settings.contains("Wednesday")) {
            ImageButton imageButton = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonWednesday);
            if (settings.getBoolean("Wednesday", true))
                imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
            else
                imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);

        }
        return viewGroup;
    }
    public void Start() {
        products.clear();
        try {
            FileInputStream read = getActivity().openFileInput("Wednesday.txt");
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(read);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String temp_read;
            while ((temp_read = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                num ++;
                products.add(new HelpAdapter(num + ")", temp_read));

            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            reader.close();
            read.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException ignore) {

        }

        num = 0;

    }




}
```

Comment: Why is your Adapter static in the first place?

Comment: I left it static for the code example